# Limiting the number of factors a ggplot2 axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, data-analysis

I'm looking to plot a numeric v/s factor plot in ggplot2 but I'm running into the following problem:
The factor variable has 26 levels due to which the X-axis is appearing extremely cluttered. How can I limit my plot to show only 9 levels of the 26?

currently, this is the code that I'm trying:

```
ggplot(flt.fin,aes(`AirportName`,`Departure Delay`, color = `AircraftType`)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(1:9),limits = c(levels(flt.fin$AirportName[1:9])))
```

I'm not very familiar with how the arguments inside scale_x_discrete work so it's possible that portion does not make any sense

Comment: Hey there! Are you looking to select the first `n` (e.g. `n = 9` in your example) levels arbitrarily? Or do you need to select something like the '9 most populated' levels?

Comment: Just as a note `levels(my_factor[1:9])` is the same as `levels(my_factor)` and will not be equal to the first 9 factor-levels.

Comment: @Johnny actually I would be interested in solutions to both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP, you have some options, depending on how your factor is structured.  Your axis is likely a factor, so setting limits does not work here.  The most straightforward way would be to simply filter your data beforehand, based on the elements you want to show.  Here's a simple example:

```
set.seed(8675309)
df <- data.frame(
  name=LETTERS,
  delay=sample(5:50, 26, replace=T)
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(name, delay)) + geom_col(width=0.5)
```

[image]

To filter that dataset to show only specific levels, you can filter beforehand:

```
names_of_interest <- c("A", "D", "E", "F", "Z", "Y")
  
df %>% dplyr::filter(name %in% names_of_interest) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, delay)) + geom_col(width=0.5)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can filter based on the numeric position of the levels of the x axis factor.  For that, you would want to first ensure the x axis was factorized, then you can use `levels(your_factor)` as a vector to specify how to filter.  Here's another example:

```
df$name <- factor(df$name)

df %>% dplyr::filter(name %in% levels(df$name)[4:15]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, delay)) + geom_col(width=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The last option is what I was looking to do.